# AMQPSSLConnection connection timeout

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, amazon-mq

I am using the PHP library php-amqplib with Amazon MQ Rabbit

When I create a new AMQPSSLConnection object with like the following:

```
$this->connection = new AMQPSSLConnection(
    $params->get('rabbit_host'),
    $params->get('rabbit_port'),
    $params->get('rabbit_username'),
    $params->get('rabbit_password'),
    $params->get('rabbit_vhost'),
    [
        'verify_peer' => false
    ],
    [
        'heartbeat' => 20,
        'connection_timeout' => 99999,
        'read_write_timeout' => 99999,
        'channel_rpc_timeout' => 99999
    ]
);
```

I get the error:

`[PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPTimeoutException] The connection timed out after 0.33181881904602 sec while awaiting incoming data`

after 60 seconds of the script running. I've tried various values for heartbeat and timeout settings but none keep the script running

Edit - This issue was caused by me passing in a timeout value to  $channel->wait(). Once I increased the 3rd parameter value (timeout), the issue was resolved

Answer (score 1):

This issue was caused by me passing in a timeout value to $channel->wait(). Once I increased the 3rd parameter value (timeout), the issue was resolved